# Laravel add to new collection from loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I have the following piece of code :

```
    $callReport = array();
    $callResult->each(function ($item) use (&$callReport) {
         $callReport[$item->date][$item->callStatus] = $item->count;
    });
```

The `$callReport` result is :

```
{
  "2020-11-25": {
    "x": 74,
    "y": 172,
  },
  "2020-11-26": {
    "x": 10,
    "y": 49,
  }
}
```

But when i try with the collect methods :

```
        $callReport = collect();
        $callResult->each(function ($item) use (&$callReport ) {
            $callReport->push($item->date, collect([$item->callStatus => $item->count]));
        });
```

I can't reach the same result :

```
[
  "2020-11-25",
  {
    "x": 74
  },
  "2020-11-25",
  {
    "y": 172
  },
  "2020-11-26",
  {
    "x": 10
  },
  "2020-11-26",
  {
    "y": 49
  }
]
```

I want to get the same result as the first one with the array using the
collect methods. What is wrong in the second piece of code?

Comment: what is `$callCenterReport` in the first code snippet, for the second one it is doing what you have asked it to do, what is the desired format

Comment: Sorry, it was a 'typo', it is `$callReport`. The desired result is the first one.

Comment: what the push does is append the data in second variable after the last key

Comment: if you are getting the output using first snippet then why not use that?

Comment: because i want to understand how to build the same structure using the collect methods.